# Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 partition not showing up in partitioning tools

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, fat32

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 alongside Windows 7. I only gave the partition about 15 gb of space, as I installed it through the installation GUI. I wanted to add some more space to it's partition, and installed GParted. When I open it, the Ubuntu partition doesn't show up. I tried using another tool on Windows, but it still didn't show. Is there any other way to increase the partition size, or have the partition show up? The windows partitions are there.

Output from sudo parted -l:

```
Model: ATA ST9500325AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary  fat16        diag
 2      106MB   15.8GB  15.7GB  primary  ntfs         boot
 3      15.8GB  500GB   484GB   primary  ntfs
```

1 is labeled DELLUTILITY (In GParted), the dell utility partition

2 is Recovery (recovery partiton)

3 is Windows' files, called OS and mounted at /host (According to GParted)

In GParted, they are located at dev/sda1, dev/sda2, and dev/sda3

UPDATE: There is a folder in my C:/ drive called ubuntu, and it has two files, which I think are the swap partition and the system files of ubuntu. I'm pretty sure that everything was installed there, but is there a way to expand the size of that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have installed using WUBI, which installs Linux to a file inside the Windows partition rather than to a separate Linux partition. To be sure, though, edit your original question and post the output of the command `sudo parted -l`, typed in a Linux command prompt window. (Please indent every line with four spaces. This will adjust the formatting to keep the output legible.)

Comment: I added the output above